# Power automate error copying calculated date column to another column in date/time format

Tags: power-automate, calculated-columns, sharepoint-list

Trying to create flow to copy the dates from several calculated date columns to another columns that are in date/time format, but keep receiving this error.

Here is my flow:

Recurrence - Sent to 1-minute frequency
SharePoint - get items - linked SharePoint site and SharePoint list (no other filters)
apply to each control - selecting SharePoint site value. then added a sharepoint update item and added SharePoint address, SharePoint list, and SharePoint ID, then, for each of the empty columns, I added dynamic fields for the calculated date columns I want to be copied into each of them.

If I change the empty columns to "single line of text" instead of "date/time", the flow works, except it copies the date and time of my calculated field and I don't want that. I want it to just copy the calculated date column and put it in empty columns specified in MM/DD/YYYY format.

Answer (score 0):

Always write dates to SharePoint columns in the format of `yyyy-MM-dd`.

What column type is your calculated column? And in your flow run, can you share what value is returned from the calculated column?